# WebServer Port in DNS configuration

Tags: dns

I need to know if there is a way to set in **`bind9`** configuration, the webserver port,
for example:

I have `10.0.1.1:8080`

and I need to have mydomain.com redirect to `10.0.1.1` on port `8080`.

Any advice will be usefull to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS does not do "port" redirection for web servers.

You either have to publish your URL with `:8080` in it, or have some other proxy service listen on port 80 that redirects your traffic to port 8080.